# Return "text/plain" while ignoring 'Accept' header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, content-type, http-accept-header

I have this piece of code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = "text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public Object test() {
    return "true";
}
```

And what I want is returning in this case "true" with 'text/plain' type even when my accept header says 'application/json' or anything else. Now I get 406 when I do that. Is there simple way to do such a thing? I mean really simple? I'd rather not change my config files that will affect more than just this one method.

**EDIT:**
I found partial solution

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@ResponseBody
public Object test(){
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    return new ResponseEntity<>("true", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But is there anyone who knows simpler, shorter solution?

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = "application/json")` how about this ?

Comment: @iamL Then I will get response with Content-Type: application/json but I want text/plain. I want somehow ignore this header

Comment: if the client is accepting only `application/json` then the producer can't violate that agreement.

Comment: set contentType : "text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1" and see if it works . Please share more detail about the client code and  request header.

Answer (score 0):

For a more flexible setting you can remove `produces = "text/plain"` and maybe add `headers ="Accept=application/json"`. see [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping):

> Mapping media types produced by a controller method is worth special attention – we can map a request based on its Accept header via the @RequestMapping headers attribute introduced above:
>
> ```
> @RequestMapping(
>   value = "/ex/foos", 
>   method = GET, 
>   headers = "Accept=application/json")
> @ResponseBody
> public String getFoosAsJsonFromBrowser() {
>     return "Get some Foos with Header Old";
> }
> ```
>
> The matching for this way of defining the Accept header is flexible – it uses contains instead of equals, so a request such as the following would still map correctly:
>
> ```
> curl -H "Accept:application/json,text/html"  http://localhost:8080/spring-rest/ex/foos
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Declare header in caller

```
accept:text/plain
```

So that you declare that *response from server as text/plain*

Here caller can be (postman, JS etc)